# Passing a Python list in a Redshift SQL query

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to pass a python list into a Redshift SQL query:

```
test = ['0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d',
      '0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb',
      '0x60e4d786628fea6478f785a6d7e704777c86a7c6']

l = tuple(test)

params = {'l': l}
```

The query is as follows:

```
conn = aws_utils.Redshift.get_redshift_engine(database_name='xxx')

query = 

  select
  collection_id,
  median(price) as price,
  date_trunc('day', "datetime") as datetime

  from asset_events
     where event_type = 'SALE'
  
      and collection_id in %(l)s
  
     group by collection_id, datetime
   

test_df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params)
```

This throws up a KeyError 'l'.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify params keyword in read_sql, because params is not 3rd  argument in doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html.

```py
test_df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=params)
```